# What kind of View should I use so to get the Title and the Url of a WebView like in the image below?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-view

[WebView with Title and Url and action menu that opens the page into Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoacr.jpg)

So you can see there is a Title "Casi di femminicidio..." and a Url just below it. On the right there is a menu which contains a button that opens the url directly into a chrome tab. I think it would be nice to show to the user the actual url and protocol like that. is it a default view type?

Comment: This a classic Toolbar, please check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
```

and then use:

```
new CustomTabsIntent
            .Builder()
            .build()
            .launchUrl(this, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
```

and if you want to change color of the bar use:

```
            .setToolbarColor()
```

more here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Good luck!